# Need script to go over 31 Loops to achieve Results

Tags: batch-file

So me and a buddy (mostly buddy) created a script for a tournament i do in UT99 so we could randomize the voted maps in however we ran into the issue. When I put more then 31 maps in the list it looks at it spits out %D value instead of a map name randomly but 31 maps or less in list never an issue. I have 46 maps in our list. Here is the script line for line. Any help in how to resolve this would be great. My buddy seems to think we need to move to power shell however neither of us are there at this time. Thanks for any help on this in advance.

```
echo on
set loop=0
set listnum=0
if EXIST maplist.csv del maplist.csv

set /p gennum=Number of map lists to generate?

rem #=============================================================
rem #===== Get list of maps from maplist.txt
rem #=============================================================

if NOT EXIST maplist.txt echo maplist.txt not found. Please create map 
list&&pause

for /f %%a in (maplist.txt) do (
    call :build_list %%a
    )

rem #=============================================================
rem #===== Generate random numbers and create maplist.csv
rem #=============================================================

:start

set /a mnum1=%random% %% %listnum% + 1

:num2

set /a mnum2=%random% %% %listnum% + 1

if %mnum2%==%mnum1% goto num2

:num3

set /a mnum3=%random% %% %listnum% + 1

if %mnum3%==%mnum1% goto num3
if %mnum3%==%mnum2% goto num3

for /F "tokens=%mnum1%,%mnum2%,%mnum3% delims=," %%B in ("%maplist%") do 
echo %%B - %%C - %%D >> maplist.csv

set /a loop=%loop% + 1
if not %loop%==%gennum% goto start

goto end

rem #=============================================================
rem #=========== Functions
rem #=============================================================
:build_list
if "%maplist%"=="" (
    set maplist=%1
    ) else (
    set maplist=%maplist%,%1
    )

set /a listnum=%listnum% + 1

goto:eof

rem #=============================================================
rem #=========== Echo number of random map lists created and open csv
rem #=============================================================
:end
echo %gennum% lists generated

maplist.csv
```

Comment: Correct.  The max is 31 tokens for the `FOR /F` command.  You will need to make multiple nested `FOR /F` commands to [get past the 31 token limit](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/clevertricks.php#FORListExtended). Why don't you assign the maplist to a pseudo array instead.

Answer (score 1):

I enabled delayed expansion and implemented a pseudo array (like Squashman suggested). Advantage: no token limit.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM next line for generating a "demo maplist":
(for /l %%a in (1,1,50) do echo Map%%a)>maplist.txt

set loop=0
set listnum=0
if EXIST maplist.csv del maplist.csv

set /p gennum=Number of map lists to generate?

rem #=============================================================
rem #===== Get list of maps from maplist.txt
rem #=============================================================

if NOT EXIST maplist.txt echo maplist.txt not found. Please create map list&&pause
set listnum=0
for /f %%a in (maplist.txt) do (
    set /a listnum+=1
    set map[!listnum!]=%%a
    )

rem #=============================================================
rem #===== Generate random numbers and create maplist.csv
rem #=============================================================

:start
set /a mnum1=%random% %% %listnum% + 1

:num2
set /a mnum2=%random% %% %listnum% + 1
if %mnum2%==%mnum1% goto num2

:num3
set /a mnum3=%random% %% %listnum% + 1
if %mnum3%==%mnum1% goto num3
if %mnum3%==%mnum2% goto num3

echo !map[%mnum1%]! - !map[%mnum2%]! - !map[%mnum3%]!>>maplist.csv
set /a loop+=1
if not %loop%==%gennum% goto start

goto end

rem #=============================================================
rem #=========== Echo number of random map lists created and open csv
rem #=============================================================
:end
echo %gennum% lists generated

maplist.csv
```

(Just a note: `CSV` stands for `Comma Separated Values` so I wouldn't expect something like `alpha - beta - gamma` - but of course that's just common agreement)

Comment: Mmmm... I don't understand what your "_pseudo_ array" term means. The [definition of _array_ term for Computer Science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array#Computer_science) given in Wikipedia is: _"a collection of same type data items that can be selected by indices computed at run-time"_, that is _exactly_ the way that `map` variable works in this code... Why did you inserted the **pseudo** word?

Comment: Awesome, perfect timing, our tournament starts this Sunday. Thanks so much for taking the time to do this.